# Como chamar uma função c# quando uma tabela SQL Server houver mudança

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Possuo o seguinte código em `C#` Asp.NET 4.5 para contar o numero de registros da minha tabela

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("consult")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
{
    try
    {
        MatrizGeneral matriz = null;
        //int count = 0;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "select count(*) from AVL_Ignition";

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                matriz.size= (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();

            }
            connection.Close();
        }
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, matriz);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Gostaria que essa função fosse executada toda vez que houvesse alguma mudança na minha tabela (sempre que houver um `insert`, `update`, etc), procurando pela Internet, encontrei algo com `SqlDependency` mas não entendi muito bem.

Como eu poderia aplicar o `SqlDependency` no meu código?

Comment: Em qual momento? Porque se pode chamar esse método (que tem problemas) no momento que fizer as operações, mas, pelo visto quer que seja automático?, mas, em qual lugar em qual momento em quais situações, explique melhor?

Comment: Olá @VirgilioNovic, desculpe pela falta de explicação.

A tabela mencionada na pergunta está sendo alterada por um equipamento da Teltonika (equipamento para gestão veicular em construção civil)que está se comunicando com o banco e preenchendo essa tabela.

Esse equipamento pode fazer varios inserts ou updates durante 1 dia, (não tenho controle sobre isso ) e pelo fato de não saber quando foi feito a ultima ou quantas alterações foram feitas na tabela, estava pensando em uma forma de fazer isso automaticamente. (SEMPRE que houver uma alteração na tabela rodasse minha função).

Comment: Espero ter  esclarecido tudo que não estava bem detalhado na pergunta.

Comment: Se o comando é feito por um equipamento, ele mesmo pode chamar paginas? porque isso é uma aplicação Web? como você vai controlar quem chama? entendeu!

Comment: Outra coisa quem vai precisar desse valor, quem vai querer esse valor ... espera que entenda que eu não entendi onde, quando e como vai ser utilizado esse valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlDependency não será adequado a um ambiente web.
O ideal será ter um trigger em .NET (CLR trigger)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/938d9dz2(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN